# How clip works in polygon union in Clipper library

Tags: c#, union, polygon, clipperlib

[image]

I use [clipper library](http://angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php). In the figure, red and black are clips and and green are polygons. The code is listed below. However, I do not understand why the resulting union polygon is `(7 3 4 14 9 1 2 6).` I assume it should be `(1 4 14 9)`? The number is vertex shown in the figure.

```
using System;
using ClipperLib;

using Polygon = System.Collections.Generic.List<ClipperLib.IntPoint>;
using Polygons = System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<ClipperLib.IntPoint>>;

namespace ClipperLibrary_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Polygons subj = new Polygons(1);
            subj.Add(new Polygon(4));
            subj[0].Add(new IntPoint(0, 0));
            subj[0].Add(new IntPoint(0, 70));
            subj[0].Add(new IntPoint(100, 70));
            subj[0].Add(new IntPoint(100, 0));

            Polygons clip = new Polygons();
            clip.Add(new Polygon(4));
            clip[0].Add(new IntPoint(40, 0));
            clip[0].Add(new IntPoint(40, 100));
            clip[0].Add(new IntPoint(150, 100));
            clip[0].Add(new IntPoint(150, 0));

            clip.Add(new Polygon(4));
            clip[1].Add(new IntPoint(-50, 0));
            clip[1].Add(new IntPoint(-50, 100));
            clip[1].Add(new IntPoint(60, 100));
            clip[1].Add(new IntPoint(60, 0));

            Polygons solution = new Polygons();
            Clipper c = new Clipper();
            c.AddPolygons(subj, PolyType.ptSubject);
            c.AddPolygons(clip, PolyType.ptClip);

            c.Execute(ClipType.ctUnion, solution, PolyFillType.pftEvenOdd, PolyFillType.pftEvenOdd);

            foreach (Polygon p in solution)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("next ");
                foreach (IntPoint pt in p)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("(" + pt.X + "; " + pt.Y + ")");
                }
            }
            //Console.WriteLine("area: " + Clipper.Area(solution[0]).ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(solution.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("right: " + c.GetBounds().right + ": left: " + c.GetBounds().left);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

If I change `PolyFillType.pftEvenOdd` to `PolyFillType.pftNonZero`, it works fine. Could anyone explain how it affects the results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because you are using the `PolyFillType.pftEvenOdd` filltype for both `subj` and `clip`.
The specified filltype operations are performed on both input sets respectively. In your example it does nothing on `subj`, but clears the common part of the two rectangles of `clip`, giving disjoint rectangles.
The union contains these two separate rectangles plus the subject unchanged.

Just change the filltype of `clip` to `PolyFillType.pftPositive` and you will get the expected result.

I used this source:

- http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper/documentation/Docs/Units/ClipperLib/Classes/Clipper/Methods/Execute.htm
- http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper/documentation/Docs/Units/ClipperLib/Types/PolyFillType.htm